# How To Search Inside an Object in MongoDB using mongoose?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, express, mongoose

Here is the object structure of 'Conversation' collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5536028a33e52be617b8bb2a"),
    "messages" : [
        {
            "from" : ObjectId("5534c58ac2bda5fe18cfcb97"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5536028a33e52be617b8bb2b"),
            "created" : ISODate("2015-04-21T07:55:54.572Z"),
            "read" : false,
            "message" : "dummy message",
            "participants" : [
                ObjectId("5534c58ac2bda5fe18cfcb97"),
                ObjectId("5530af38576214dd3553331c")
            ]
        }
    ],
    "participants" : [
        ObjectId("5530af38576214dd3553331c")
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Using the following code I got the object

```
collection.findById(id,function(err,conv){})
```

Now using this object I need to find whether the participants array (inside the object )  contains the object id `'5530af38576214dd3553331c'`. How to find inside an object using mongoose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [**`find()`**](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-find) method, your query object will have the `id` and the `participants` fields:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var participant_id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5530af38576214dd3553331c");
var query = { _id: id, participants: participant_id };

Conversation.find(query)
            .exec(function(err, conv){
               // Handle err
            });
```

Comment: Thank you so much chridam :) It did work :) One more Question
There are many objects in the collection and each objects has participants array. I want to list the objects which is having particular element (here object) in the 'particular' array. How can I do that ?

Comment: As for your other question, I'm not sure if I got you right but it would be great if you could create a new question with the sufficient details like the sample documents and the expected result from a query.

Answer (score 0):

you can just use mongoose `find`

```
collection.find({participants: <your participant id here>}).exec(callback)
```